# Ho do I Integrate the CKEditor into react app without error

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I am trying to integrate the ckeditor into a react app. I get the following errors:

> ckeditor.tsx:156 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'getAttribute')
> at IconView._updateXMLContent (iconview.js:67:1)
> at IconView.render (iconview.js:48:1)
> at IconView. (observablemixin.js:181:1)
> at IconView.fire (emittermixin.js:146:1)
> at  [as render] (observablemixin.js:184:1)
> at ViewCollection._renderViewIntoCollectionParent (viewcollection.js:179:1)
> at ViewCollection. (viewcollection.js:63:1)
> at ViewCollection.fire (emittermixin.js:146:1)
> at ViewCollection.addMany (collection.js:106:1)
> at ViewCollection.add (collection.js:75:1) {phase: 'initialization', willEditorRestart: false} (anonymous) @
> ckeditor.tsx:156 Promise.catch (async)
> _initializeEditor @ ckeditor.tsx:151 await in _initializeEditor (async) componentDidMount @ ckeditor.tsx:102 commitLayoutEffectOnFiber
> @ react-dom.development.js:23305 commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @
> react-dom.development.js:24688 commitLayoutEffects_begin @
> react-dom.development.js:24674 commitLayoutEffects @
> react-dom.development.js:24612 commitRootImpl @
> react-dom.development.js:26823 commitRoot @
> react-dom.development.js:26682 finishConcurrentRender @
> react-dom.development.js:25981 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
> react-dom.development.js:25809 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
> flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
> scheduler.development.js:533 editorwatchdog.js:160 Uncaught (in
> promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'model')
> at editorwatchdog.js:160:1

i am using the example from the ckeditor page. This is the code:

```
import './ContentCreator.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';

// NOTE: Use the editor from source (not a build)!
import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';

import { Essentials } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials';
import { Bold, Italic } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles';
import { Paragraph } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph';

const editorConfiguration = {
    plugins: [ Essentials, Bold, Italic, Paragraph ],
    toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ]
};

class ContentCreator extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ContentCreator">
                <h2>Using CKEditor 5 from source in React</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    config={ editorConfiguration }
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }
                    onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
                    } }
                    onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
                    } }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContentCreator;
```

Well at least the example should run...